# Filter rows from a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have got a string stored in a dataframe column

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": 1, "content": "froyay-xcd = (E)-cut-2-froyay-xcd"}, index=[0])
print(df)
idx = df[df['content'].str.contains("froyay-xcd  = (E)-cut-2-froyay-xcd")]
print(idx)
```

I'm trying to find the index of the row that contains a search string and the following warning occurs

```
UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
  return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I'm not sure why an empty dataframe is returned when the search string actually is present in the dataframe columns.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. I expect the output to return the row stored in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `regex=False` parameter for avoid convert values to regex, here `()` are special regex characters:

```
idx = df[df['content'].str.contains("froyay-xcd = (E)-cut-2-froyay-xcd", regex=False)]
print(idx)
   ID                            content
0   1  froyay-xcd = (E)-cut-2-froyay-xcd
```

Or you can escape regex by:

```
import re

idx = df[df['content'].str.contains(re.escape("froyay-xcd = (E)-cut-2-froyay-xcd"))]
print(idx)
   ID                            content
0   1  froyay-xcd = (E)-cut-2-froyay-xcd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `\` before `(` and `)` to avoid it and then get index using `.index`

```
df.content.str.contains("froyay-xcd = \(E\)-cut-2-froyay-xcd").index
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

If you have more regex special character better to use `regex=False` as @jezrael said.